# XamDatagrid UnboundField Checkbox Binding is not working

Tags: checkbox, binding, xamdatagrid

Help needed. Why the below binding is not working. I want to have checkbox on each row of data. When the checkbox is checked/unchecked, it should invoke some event.

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CheckboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
                         <CheckBox Command="{Binding DataContext.IsCheckedBoolean, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</Grid.Resources>



<igDP:UnboundField Label="Action" Width="auto">
      <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
            <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource CheckboxStyle}" />
       </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>
```

In order to test the binding, I use the below property returned in my viewmodel. The default value is false.

```
public Boolean IsCheckedBoolean
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsCheckedBoolean");
        }
    }
```

I'm referring to this [WPF Binding : Add Button to Unbound Field in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042873/wpf-binding-add-button-to-unbound-field-in-grid)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to invoke some `command` on `CheckBox` check/uncheck `event` than:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type rControl:GridView}},Path=DataContext.ReviewRequiredCommand}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsChecked}"
       BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Gray"/>
```

`CommandParameter` to send `CheckBox` check status as argument of `command`.

If you want to bind a `property` then as per you code:

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsCheckedBoolean, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}}}" />
```

(**but since you are using this one `property` to `cellValuePresenterStyle`. You won't be able to find out from which `cell` this `binding` is getting reflected. I Hope that's not a problem for you.**):